# Linear Transformation: P2(R) -> P3(R)

Tags: linear-algebra

I have to verify the dimension formula for this:

$T: P2(R)->P3(R) $ defined by $T(f(x))=xf(x)+f'(x)$

I have worked out that the null space of T is when f(x) is = 0. But isn't the range all of $P3(R)$ and therefore dim(N(T))+dim(R(T)) would be bigger than dim(P2(R))?

Can someone please tell me where I went wrong, thanks

Comment: If you write out $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$ and then calculate $T(f(x))$, you might find the coefficients of $T(f(x))$ must obey a linear relationship.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use the same expression $T(p) = ax^3 + bx^2 + (c + 2a)x + b$ to find a basis for the range of $T$. We can write $T(p)$, for any $p$, as $a(x^3 + 2x) + b(x^2 + 1) + cx$. Therefore, ${x^3 + 2x, x^2 + 1, x}$ is a spanning set. Each is linearly independent, so it is a basis. Notice also that this satisfies the rank-nullity theorem: the dimension of $P_2(ℝ) = 3$, the dimension of $N(T)$ is 0, so the dimension of $R(T)$ must be 3. We got 3 vectors for the basis, so all is well and good.

Comment: thanks a lot, this is perfect